# How to convince a user to make an face to face interview?

Tags: interview

I need help with convincing user to meet with our company responsable for an interview. We are calling them and telling them that we want to make an interview with them ,and telling them our purpose is to give you better service through their feedbacks. 
We are also offering them quite good amount off discount (almost 150 dollars). But it is still hard to convince a lot of users. So what can we do to make meet with us only for an hour and collect their reward. 
Do you have any method or script that might convince users to make an face to face interview. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Do you require them to come to you? If so, a good alternative can be to offer them a visit instead.

Comment: You've told us what they have to gain (ie, $150 discount), but have you determined what they have to lose, in terms of cost and time to get your location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found back then, that the money-reward often is not necessary. Nearly all of our test subjects liked to "have an influence on what is happening" - so if your presentation is perfect, they might give you more than you asked for.

Provide them a coffee, some pastries, laugh with them, give them a good time - and inform them as soon as you implemented their input with a big, fat, thank-you message.

You want involved testers, no bought opinions!

But, to be honest, this works better when you go outside. I would always prefer field research over inviting people to my office. Why? The answers are better (natural environment, more comfortable for testers, real answers on real scenarios, ...), people are more relaxed.

Try the "Star Bucks Test" - if you can do that: Sit down in a Starbucks (or any restaurant of choice), confront people directly by buying them a coffee and then... have a nice chat.

Best results I had came from that setup. I can absolutely recommend trying this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider who your users are. Incentives for testing need to match the value your users put on their time. If your users are company directors, their time is likely to be worth more to them than a college students.

Have you communicated to the potential participants what they will be getting out of the session. Users often like to be involved and feel they are having input into the design of a product or service. Presenting the testing to the participants in a way that will resonate is essential.

Can you test with the users in their workplace or an neutral environment. Try to find out why the users don't want to participate. It could be the time, location or that they don't feel they are qualified to participate.

If the location is an issue, it may be appropriate to consider remote testing. There are lots of services available to help you with this. It may be that screen sharing or a video call may be really useful.

How many users do you need? Behaviour is relatively consistent so you might not need a huge number of participants. And remember testing 1 user is better than testing no users.

Finally have you considered using a recruitment agency. They may be able to take the pain out of the process.